# Google Plus Follow buttons onclick events

Tags: javascript, google-plus

The documentation for the Google+ buttons shows that the +1 button has a callback attribute for when it is clicked, but the Follow button does not. It there any way to detect when a visitor has clicked the Follow button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CallBack response for google+ follow button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699899/callback-response-for-google-follow-button)