# CallBack response for google+ follow button

Tags: events, callback, google-plus

I need a callback event when a user is successfully logged into the Google+ at time of follow button click.

This code is not giving any callback response :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
    <script>
        function plusClick(data) {
            //Nothing working
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-onstartinteraction="tester" data-callback="plusClick" data-height="20" data-href="//plus.google.com/u/0/115175605005410528191" data-rel="author"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Callbacks are not [documented](https://developers.google.com/+/web/follow/) as being supported for the follow widget.