# How to capture callback event in Google Plus Follow Button?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am using Google + Follow button. Is there any way to capture the callback event for the Google+ follow button.

```
<div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-callback="onCallback" data-height="20" data-href="https://plus.google.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" data-rel="publisher"></div>

function onCallback(args) {
  alert(args);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CallBack response for google+ follow button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699899/callback-response-for-google-follow-button)

Comment: What is the solution for handling callback in Google+ follow button?

Comment: There isn't one. You can't do it.